# How can I include a script element in a Handlebars template?

Tags: javascript, html, handlebars.js, express-handlebars

So I'm trying to create a client-side JavaScript file for one of my .hbs templates. But it doesn't seem to even load the .js file when i add a  tag in the html code. I have looked around for a solution but I can't find any clear answer for handlebars, at least not one I can understand.

I have tried:
specifying type="text/javascript"
adding the  tag in main.hbs right below {{{body}}} just to see if it works but nothing happend.
Playing around with the .js file but it clearly doesn't get executed.

## booking-functions.hbs

```
console.log("test")
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
console.log("In bookingfunctions")

// bunch of code

})
```

## booking.hbs

````
    <div>
     <script src="../functions/booking-functions.js"></script>
     // Bunch of html that works fine with handlebars
    </div>
    ```
    main.hbs
    ======
    ```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
     // Nothing javascript or handlebars related here
    </head>
    <body>
        // Navbarcode and such

        //Login check with #if handlebars

        {{{body}}}

    </body>
    </html>
````

## app.js

```
    const path = require('path')
    const express = require('express')
    const expressHandlebars = require('express-handlebars')

    const variousRouter = require('./routers/various-router')
    const accountRouter = require('./routers/account-router')
    const bookingRouter = require('./routers/booking-router')


    const app = express() 

    //Session code here

    // Setup express-handlebars.
    app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'))

    app.engine('hbs', expressHandlebars({
        extname: 'hbs',
        defaultLayout: 'main',
        layoutsDir: path.join(__dirname, 'layouts')
    }))

    // Handle static files in the public folder.
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))


    //body parser middleware
    app.use(express.json());
    app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:false}));

    // Attach all routers.
    app.use('/', variousRouter)
    app.use('/accounts', accountRouter)
    app.use('/booking', bookingRouter)
```

Comment: Check if the script url works, open the page, check the source code in the browser, and click in the script src (`../functions/booking-functions.js`), if that opens the js file correctly is a js problem (but i strongly believe that route is not accesible).

Comment: Clicking it take me to: 
localhost:port/functions/booking-functions, which i cannot GET

Comment: So I am obviously quite new to this. But what happens is that when the browser reads the <script> tag it sends a GET request to localhost:8080/functions/booking-funtions.js. 

So what I am wondering now is am I supposed to have a response in my router file like when I make requests for a web page? And how do you respond with a js file while staying on the web page?

Comment: That file should be on your `public` folder so the browser can request it as a static file

Comment: I have tried that aswell, I still get 404 not found.